# Unable to ssh EC2 using password - "Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)"

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, putty, ubuntu-14.04

I have followed the following steps

https://coderwall.com/p/j5nk9w

This is what I did

1) $ sudo useradd -s /bin/bash -m -d /home/newuser  -g root newuser

Entered the Password for the newuser

2)$ sudo visudo
And added after root
newuser  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

3) $ sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Changed and set PasswordAuthentication as yes in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

4) sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart 
Restarted the sshd

But when I try to login via Putty I get the following error:

"Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)"

This is my /etc/ssh/sshd_config file

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin without-password
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
```

I understand this is risky and this is not for a public project.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Rather than linking to a separate page, can you show which actual commands you ran (without the passwords of course)? That should give us a better idea of what's happening.

Comment: I modified the post to include the steps I took.

Comment: @Samosa check logs, also try to create another user and do not include it to `root` group.

Answer (score 3):

As others noted at the linked page, **this is a bad idea.** Passwords are generally much less secure than using public/private key pairs.

That said, if the server sent just `publickey` it isn't using the new configuration yet. Try restarting `sshd`.

Answer (score 0):

1. `vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config`
2. Edit the file

   ```
   # Authentication:
   LoginGraceTime 120
   PermitRootLogin without-password
   StrictModes yes
   ```

   Please edit the `permitRootLogin` in the file shown above.

   After the changes:

   ```
   # Authentication:
   LoginGraceTime 120
   PermitRootLogin yes
   StrictModes
   ```
3. Please restart your ssh service using this command:

   ```
   /etc/init.d/ssh restart
   ```

Answer (score -2):

To save some Ubuntu neophytes like myself some time, newer Ubuntu instances no longer use sshd reload. Instead it is asking for:

```
sudo restart ssh
```

Please see this SO link for more details: https://superuser.com/questions/214799/no-etc-init-d-sshd-file-ubuntu-ec2

Comment: This is entirely unrelated to the actual problem.